# Can we control optical zoom value manually for iOS camera?

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcapturedevice, ios-camera

I want to add an optical zoom level to the custom value for the ios camera, Can we achieve this for all iPhone devices depending on their camera type?
I have tried this but I am not sure about this is correct or not.

```
if let device = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video {
 try! device.lockForConfiguration()
 device.videoZoomFactor = 1.0
 device.unlockForConfiguration()                               
 }
```

Comment: It's not correct. Saying `try!` is never right.